# How can I prove that every term in this sequence is postive?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence that satisfying:

$(i)$ the sequence is decreasing: $$a_n \ge a_{n+1} \forall n \in \mathbb N$$
$(ii)$ the sequence is converging to $0$: $$(a_n) \rightarrow 0$$

The proof must be sure to use the definition of convergence: $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge N$, we have $|a_n|\lt \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$. But I have no idea how to find out what that epsilon is in order to prove that $a_n \gt 0 \forall n \in \mathbb N$

Please help me prove that every term in this sequence is positive. I thank you very much. I have spent hours of trying to set up some epsilons, but it is useless.

Comment: Suppose for contradiction that there existed a term which was negative. Then since the sequence is decreasing...

Comment: If $a_n$ is ever negative then pick a nbhd of $0$ not containing it.

Comment: You can prove every term is non-negative, but the sequence $0,0,0,0,\ldots$ satisfies by $(i)$ and $(ii)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What's interesting is proving the converse! (if $0$ is $\inf$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By contradiction if there existed $n_0$ such that $a_{n_0} < 0$ then $\forall n\ge n_0$: $a_n \le a_{n_0} < 0$. Take $\epsilon = -\frac{a_{n_0}}{2}$ for contradiction.

Of course we've shown only non-negativity, since the sequence can be constant and equal to 0 from some $n_0$.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but $\epsilon$ must be GREATER than $0$. In your proof, it is smaller than $0$.

Comment: Sorry, of course I must have missed a minus sign. I meant absolute value of that number. I see someone just have corrected me, thanks :)

Comment: I am sorry, but I still did not see any contradiction: if you take the absolute value of $a_n$, then there is a chance that it still satisfies the inequality $|a_n|\lt -\fraction{a_n_0}{2}$

Comment: These are negative numbers, so $$|a_n| \ge |a_{n_0}| > |\frac{a_{n_0}}{2}| $$.

Comment: WOW...YOU ARE TRULY A GENIUS !!!! I THANK YOU VERY MUCH, SIR !